# Ajax редактирование количества товаров Opencart 2.0

Tags: ajax, opencart, cart

Есть уже существующий метод в common.js cart.update($key,$quantity);
Ajax работает. Отправляет в метод controller/checkout/cart.php
Там есть три метода add, edit, remove, Добавление и удаление работают отлично, а вот редактирование не работает. Кто сталкивался?
Вот скрин, того что выбивает в ответ на редактирование товара
[image: Opencart cart.update]

Comment: когда задаёте вопрос по опенкарту не забывайте указывать его версию. кроме того, всегда указывайте, используется ли окмоды/расширения в отношении функционала, который описываете. это даст гораздо более чёткую картину проблемы. также разные шаблоны могут сильно отличаться по способу реализации функционала.

Comment: Наверно вы используете какую-то кастомную тему потому, что в oc2.0.x обновление количества товара в корзине происходит post-сабмитом всей формы корзины на метод checkout/cart/edit. В любом случае вардампте массив post, приходящий в контроллер в метод edit, далее смотрите весь путь данных вплоть до модели. И не забудьте консоль. Более помочь можно только просматривая код. Удачи.

Comment: В /cart редактирует, но я хочу настроить нормальную корзину) и вызвать метод на onclick=cart.edit(key,quantity); не получается)